# How can I search for broken links of a website using Java?

Tags: java, web-crawler, broken-links

I would like to scan some websites looking for broken links, preferably using Java. Any hint how can I start doing this?

(I know there are some websites that do this, but I want to make my own personalized log file)

Comment: Are these websites utilizing AJAX ? You can download/parse whole (X)HTML code using let's say `HttpURLConnection` class with `JTidy`, but it's not that simple for dynamic AJAX websites. You might take a look at Selenium Java API for such case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a web-crawler isn't as simple as just reading the static HTML, if the page uses JavaScript to modify the DOM then it gets complex.  You will also need to look for pages you've already visited aka Spider Traps?  If the site is pure static HTML, then go for it...  But if the site uses Jquery and is large, expect it to be complex.

If your site is all static, small and has little or no JS then use the answers already listed.

Or

You could use [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org/) and then later parsed it's crawl.log for 404's.   [Heritrix doc on crawl.log](http://crawler.archive.org/articles/user_manual/analysis.html#logs)

Or **If you most write your own:**

You could use something like [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) (it has a JavaScript engine) to load the page, then query the DOM object for links.  Then place each link in a "unvisited" queue, then pull links from the unvisited queue to get your next url to load, if the page fails to load, report it.

To avoid duplicate pages (spider traps) you could hash each link and keep a HashTable of visited pages (see [CityHash](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/) ).  Before placing a link into the unvisited queue check it against the visited hashtable.

To avoid leaving your site check that the URL is in a safe domain list before adding it to the unvisited queue.  If you want to confirm that the off domain links are good, then keep them in a offDomain queue.  Then later load each link from this queue using URL.getContent(url) to see if they work (faster than using HTMLUnit and you don't need to parse the page anyway.).

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which recursively checks links.
Pseudo Code:

```
function checklinks(String url){
     try{
         content=HTTP.getContents(url);
         String[] links=content.getAllRegexMatches('href="(http://.*?)"');
         foreach(links as String link)
              checklinks(link)
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Link "+url" failed");
     }
}
```

Depending on the Links you have to complete the link passed to the next recursion by adding the url relative to the current URL.

Comment: `foreach(links as String link)` when did they add it to Java?

Comment: Also make sure that you don't process the entire internet if there is external link.

Comment: @Alex that was added since pseudo-java 1.0

Comment: @OscarRyz it seems that they also added `function` there... Or was it 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

1. Load website front page using some HTTP client for Java
2. Parse HTML (since it's not well formed XML you may need to clean it up first. With something like tagsoup)
3. For every `<a>` tag, get its content and attempt to connect to it.

If necessary, repeat recursively if URL from `<a>` belongs to your site. Make sure to store URLs that you processed already in a map so you don't do it more than once.